# setOnClickListener doesn't work using Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a simple button that changes the fragment, it doesn't give any error, it just doesn't work.

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.follow.FollowFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="background"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/btn_col"
            android:text="Log In" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment code:

```
class FollowFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = FollowFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: FollowViewModel
    private lateinit var loginButton: Button
    private lateinit var viewFollow: View

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_follow, container, false)
        viewFollow = root
        loginButton = viewFollow.findViewById(R.id.loginButton)
        var loginFragment = LoginFragment()
        println("Hello :(")
        loginButton.setOnClickListener {
            println("Hello :)")
            //parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, loginFragment).commit()
        }

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_follow, container, false)

    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(FollowViewModel::class.java)
        // TODO: Use the ViewModel
    }

}
```

Only the sad hello is printed, it seems to recognize the button, but the listener don't work. The app has a bottom navigation bar, and the screens are fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By returning `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_follow, ...)` you're inflating a second layout to be used for your fragment instead of the one that you're using to set the listener.

You should be returning `root`.